# Possible Methods to Restore Speed of File Sharing (AFP) in OS X 10.10?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, afp

I have an iMac and a MacBook Pro under the same network connected through AFP file sharing protocol. Before I upgraded to OS X 10.10, the speed is very fast - copying a 200MB file would take a couple of seconds. Now as I have upgraded to 10.10, the speed slowed down drastically. When I copy a 200MB file it took me around 10 or 15 minutes. The iMac is connected to the router directly through Ethernet and the MacBook Pro is connected through wifi.

Comment: Yosemite & wifi don't seem to be the best of friends. Try wired & see if the issue disappears.

Comment: I am not inspired to find wired solutions because the laptop is meant to move around freely in the house. I can sometimes transfer files to my iMac on bed or in my couch without wasting time setting up a wired connection.

Answer (score 1):

AFP is more so meant for a LAN configuration and not a WAN network. Instead you could try CIFS or another protocol and see if you see the same speed or an increase.

I would also try to use AirDrop and see how that works.

Comment: I don't see anything in the OP's post to suggest it's anything other than LAN

Comment: One of his devices is connected via LAN the other is connected via Wifi.

Comment: SMB (CIFS) does improve the speed of file transferring, however it does not restore the speed of my file transferring to before I upgraded to Yosemite. Now copying 200MB files will take two or three minutes. It is still massively slower than the speed I had before.

Comment: Hmmm this could be an issue with Yosemite. Are you on 10.10.1?

Comment: Correct. Correct.